# Не создается проект в NetBeans 8.2

Tags: linux, netbeans, linux-mint

Версия IDE: NetBeans 8.2
Ось:Linux Mint 18.2
JDK-9

По нажатию создания нового проекта ничего не происходит.
В чем может состоять проблема?

Comment: Как ты устанавливал NetBeans?

Comment: @don Rumata Устанавливал через .sh 
В итоге решил проблему тем, что установил через менеджер программ.

Comment: Ну собсно это и я хотел посоветовать

Comment: @don Rumata Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Установите дополнительно jdk-8u152. В настройках netbeans укажите путь к jdk на неё - /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152 или запускайте среду разработки с  параметром  --jdkhome вот так: 
//netbeans --jdkhome /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152